# Task Manager Blocks Java Mouse Mover Program

Tags: java, windows

I've quickly programmed a java program that randomly moves the cursor to prank my mate. Everything works perfectly except that when Task Manager is the current active window, the cursor doesn't move. It works fine when other applications are active. My questions are: What is causing this and if possible, how do i fix it. Here's my code(i know it's messy.):

```
    Robot rob = new Robot();

    while (true) {
        PointerInfo pointer = MouseInfo.getPointerInfo();
        Point point = pointer.getLocation();

        int x = (int) point.getX();
        int y = (int) point.getY();
        int xd = getRandomDirection();
        int yd = getRandomDirection();

        rob.mouseMove(x+xd, y+yd);
    }

    private static int getRandomDirection() {
        Random ran = new Random();
        float ran1 = ran.nextFloat();

        if(ran1 > 0.5){
            return 1;
        }else{
            return -1;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer. Simply it is a rule in the newer versions of windows that a program that is not "run as admin" can't control over an admin-run program, e.g task manager. The simple solution was enabling the little checkbox on the program in windows with "rightclick" > "properties" > "Compatibility" > "Run as admin" or simply manually running as admin every time with a simple rightclick.